# Only DRBG is used for PGP or could use other PRNG?

Tags: random-number-generator, pgp

-RFC4880 refer to DRBG at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-16.2
-Could we apply other PRNG such as enocoro/photon for pgp?

Comment: You mean for a PGP **fork** like PGP-v.2?

Comment: DRBG is just another name for (CS)PRNG.